# Change text on the click of a button, JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JavaScript expanding and collapsing text on the click of a button. What I want to do is add a "+" sign next to the button and change it to "-" when the text is collapsed and vice-versa.

This is my HTML:

```
<button onclick="expand('one')">First text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="one">
      A bunch of text here
</div>


<p><button onclick="expand('two')">Second text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="two">
      More text here
</div>


<p><button onclick="expand('three')">Third text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="three">
      And some text here
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

And this is JavaScript:

```
function expand(textId) {
    var e = document.getElementById(textId);
    var sign = document.getElementsByClassName("plusminus");
    if (e.style.display === "block") {
        e.style.display = "none";
        sign.innerText = "+";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "block";
        sign.innerText = "-";
    }
}
```

The expand/collapse works, but not changing the sign... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Several problems here. Firstly, your markup is invalid as you're not closing the `p` tags. Secondly, your selector is currently selecting ALL `plusmin` elements, not the one relative to the area being expanded/collapsed. Finally, inline DOM-zero events via HTML attributes are pretty archaic. Consider centralised event handling via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I think I know how to fix it, will try later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array. You are treating it as a single object.

Your implementation of `document.getElementsByClassName` is not correct, you have multiple spans with same class, you need to pick the correct one using index. keeping mind in your existing code I have done a small correction in your expand function.

```js
function expand(textId, index) {
    var e = document.getElementById(textId);
    var sign =  document.getElementsByClassName("plusminus")[index];
    if (e.style.display === "block") {
        e.style.display = "none";
        sign.innerText = "+";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "block";
        sign.innerText = "-";
    }
}
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
   
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="expand('one',0)">First text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="one">
      A bunch of text here
</div>


<p><button onclick="expand('two',1)">Second text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="two">
      More text here
</div>


<p><button onclick="expand('three',2)">Third text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="three">
      And some text here
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's improve the code by converting to centralised event handling via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than multiple, inline event attributes muddying the HTML.

In preparation for this, we need to transfer the flag ("one", "two") etc to a data attribute to each button. So the HTML becomes:

```
<p>
    <button data-which="three">Third text</button>
    <span class="plusminus">+</span>
</p> <!-- <-- note missing closing P tag in your original markup -->
```

So in an external JS file you'd do something like:

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-which]');
[].forEach.call(btns, function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        expand(this.getAttribute('data-which'));
    }, false);
});
```

Your other problem is that the `expand()` function currently targets ALL `plusminus` elements, not the one relative to the area being expanded/collapsed. Let's fix that:

```
var sign = document.querySelector('#'+textId).parentNode.querySelector('.plusminus');
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hp6v3qtr)

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the list of class `classList` to check if class `text` was applied to the element.
- Use the `nextElementSibling` to get the minus/plus element.

```
function expand(button, textId) {
  var e = document.getElementById(textId);
  if (e.classList.contains('text')) {
    e.classList.remove('text');
    button.nextElementSibling.innerText = "-"
  } else {
    e.classList.add('text');
    button.nextElementSibling.innerText = "+"
  }
}
```

## Look at this code snippet

```js
function expand(button, textId) {
  var e = document.getElementById(textId);
  if (e.classList.contains('text')) {
    e.classList.remove('text');
    button.nextElementSibling.innerText = "-"
  } else {
    e.classList.add('text');
    button.nextElementSibling.innerText = "+"
  }
}
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="expand(this, 'one')">First text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="one">
  A bunch of text here
</div>
<p/>
<button onclick="expand(this, 'two')">Second text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="two">
  More text here
</div>
<p/>

<button onclick="expand(this, 'three')">Third text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="three">
  And some text here
</div>
```

See? now, your minus/plus element is changing.

## Better approach

- Bind a click event to the button using `addEventListener` function.
- Add a `target` as data attribute `data-target` to your button, i.e `data-target='one'`

## Look at this code snippet

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(b) {
  b.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    expand(e.currentTarget, e.currentTarget.dataset.target);
  });
});


function expand(button, textId) {
  var e = document.getElementById(textId);
  if (e.classList.contains('text')) {
    e.classList.remove('text');
    button.nextElementSibling.innerText = "-"
  } else {
    e.classList.add('text');
    button.nextElementSibling.innerText = "+"
  }
}
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button data-target='one'>First text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="one">
  A bunch of text here
</div>
<p/>
<button data-target='two'>Second text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="two">
  More text here
</div>
<p/>

<button data-target='three'>Third text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span>
<div class="text" id="three">
  And some text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate lots of mistakes and errors by following best practices:

- Don’t use `onclick` attributes
- Use event delegation
- Use CSS classes to toggle styles instead of direct `style` changes

Also, close `<p>`s properly and keep in mind that `<div>`s can’t be inside a `<p>`.

Now, your most important issue was that you misunderstood [what `getElementsByClassName` returns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/4642212): an `HTMLCollection`, rather than a single element. `innerText` doesn’t mean anything on it.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function expand(e) {
  if (e.target.dataset.expand) {
    let textElement = document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.expand),
      expandIndicator = e.target.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("plusminus")[0];

    expandIndicator.innerText = (textElement.classList.toggle("show")
      ? "-"
      : "+");
  }
});
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p><button data-expand="one">First text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span></p>
<div id="one" class="text">
  A bunch of text here
</div>

<p><button data-expand="two">Second text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span></p>
<div id="two" class="text">
  More text here
</div>

<p><button data-expand="three">Third text</button><span class="plusminus">+</span></p>
<div id="three" class="text">
  And some text here
</div>
```

Instead of `onclick` attributes you could use `data-*` attributes to store the ID of the element you want to show. By event delegation (testing for `e.target`’s properties), you can select the correct `textElement`.

To find the correct `expandIndicator` you can go back to your parent element (`<p>`) and find an element with `class="plusminus"` from there. Remember to select the first one (`[0]`), since you’ll still get an `HTMLCollection`.

You could alternatively use `expandIndicator = e.target.nextElementSibling`, if the `<span class="plusminus">` always comes after the button — here, the class name doesn’t event matter.

Finally, instead of testing for the `style` property, consider using class toggling instead. `.classList.toggle` conveniently returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the class has been set or not, which can directly be used in a ternary expression (… `?` … `:` …).